# Prevent Chrome from adding 'www.' and '.com' to 'localhost' on omnibox Alt+Enter

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, browser

When I type in 'localhost/path/to/file' and hit Alt+Enter to open it in a new tab, Chrome seems to change it to 'www.localhost.com/path/to/file', which obviously fails to resolve. Is there any way to change Chrome's behavior so as to open 'localhost/path/to/file' in a new tab?

Comment: When you write file, can I assume you are including the extension? Can I also assume you are trying to use Chrome as a file browser instead of an internet browser?

Comment: Enter `http://localhost`, that'll work

Comment: @DaveRook, the OP is using "localhost" so chrome is still functioning as a web browser.

Comment: @Dave: Of course, 'localhost/Events/event.php?name=Flawless' is what I'm really typing out. As you can see, I'm using it as an internet browser, not a file browser.

Comment: @slhck: It still doesn't seem to work. Same transformation.

Comment: In that case, the reason you are getting this is because the page isn't found, and Chrome is looking externally for it. I assume IIS is set up and configured?

Comment: @Dave: It works fine when I explicitly open up a new tab and type in the same URL. Of course 'www.localhost.com' won't work, because localhost is an alias for ::1 or 127.0.0.1 while localhost.com is a TLD. Also, I'm using wampserver, not IIS.

Comment: You could try binding the word localhost to your site?

Comment: @Dave: Binding the word? How would I go about doing that?
Anyway, I'd like to change things on the end of Chrome, since patching up a website just to make it more convenient for me to load it up locally seems less than ideal.

Comment: Well the quick and dirty hack would be to add localhost.com 127.0.0.1 to your Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file and reboot...

Comment: @SohamPal but your decision is to force Chrome into something it doesn't want to do by default; to me, both are less than ideal, but are 50:50, plus Xyon's excellent suggestion means it's not even browser specific!

Comment: @Xyon: Great suggestion. Will use it for now, thanks.

Comment: @Dave: I remember being able to get around this somehow in Chrome in the past (perhaps by using 'http://' as slhck suggested), but I can't seem to get it to work. It seems a simple enough task to warrant implementation since I remember being able to do this painlessly on Firefox. Oh well, thanks. :)

Comment: @SohamPal - I'm sorry, can you confirm what you are expecting here. Do you want to see a 404 or similar if the page can't be found, or are you expecting to see a 'html' page?

Comment: @Dave: I am indeed expecting a HTTP 200 OK response.

Comment: Does that work, soham?

Comment: @Xyon: Yeah, did the job well for now. :D Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This now seems to be the new default behavior in Chrome.

Tested on Chrome Version 29.0.1547.65 (Xubuntu 13.04).

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, click:

> Tools - Options- Under the hood - Change Proxy setting  and then click on LAN Setting

Check "Bypass proxy server for local address"

Comment: I'm not using a proxy.